# How to collect core dumps from unit tests?

Tags: c++, linux, gitlab-ci, coredump

What is the easiest way to collect core dumps from unit tests job in ci? Tests are run with CTest if important. I can set up kernel_pattern and write the corresponding path in the artifacts, but I still need to copy the executable file of the crashed application with symbols, which is no longer so trivial. Or is there another way to get a dump with symbols at once, without having to look for an executable?

Comment: What problem exactly are you having with this? If you need to run some commands to collect information after job script failure, maybe consider using `after_script` ?

Comment: Just add the executable and core dump to your build's artifacts?

Comment: @sytech The problem is that I am running all tests in one task, i.e.  I have a lot of executables.  сore_pattern contains %E with a file path, but it could be incorrectly converted if the name included '!'.  Copying all crash tests to artifacts is not very good. I want to upload only necessary exe with dumps.

Comment: I see. On that, would it be fair to rephrase the key question as "How do I find/filter the _relevant_ (executable files|symbols|core dumps) when my tests fail?" -- In other words, the problem is more with locating the right files, not necessarily artifacting/uploading them -- If you could produce and/or _locate_ the relevant files (and relevant files _only_ ), you could easily move them into a directory that will be collected as an artifact and your problem would be solved; does that sound right?

Comment: @sytech Yes you are right.  I just hoped that gitlab provides the solution itself for such a seemingly common scenario.  As a result, I wrote a one-line script that calls `file` on a dump, parses the output and copies the exe along the resulting path.